# Is it possible to query with two global secondary indexes?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

When I try to use `QueryRequest` of `amazon-dynamodb` through indexname it says

> Query Key not supported

How to query two global secondary index? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can't query using more than one index at the same time. Fundamentally, using more than one index to make a single query just doesn't make any sense.

Perhaps you meant to ask if you could use different indexes to perform different queries on the same table in which case the answer is yes.

Or perhaps you meant to ask whether you can perform a complex query that involves joining or otherwise filtering data using multiple indexes, in which case the answer is unfortunately, no - not in a single query, at least. DynamoDB doesn't support serverside joins. You have to make multiple queries (which can each use a different index) and then aggregate client-side.

--
Update

Based on the error you said you are getting it looks like you haven't correctly specified the hash/range key(s) for your query using a global secondary index.

Have a look at the docs for instructions on how to query with a secondary index: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Querying